# To clear the cache programmatically

Tags: android, caching

I want to clear the cache of the other installed applications in my device through my app.Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, it would be a massive security flaw in Android if one application could clear another.

Comment: There are some applications on the market which can clear the cache of other apps

Comment: Namely, Smart RAM Booster. I am also wondering how they accomplish this, even without the need to root the phone.

Comment: Actually, you can do this. And it isn't a security flaw. By definition **cache** is just a temporary holding place for data, but the data is never guaranteed to actually be there. It is just an optimization. Any app that relies on something being in the **cache** is broken. Interestingly enough, you can delete files from the cache, but you cannot put files in another application's cache and you can't read files from another application's cache. Now **that** would be a security flaw.